# PRMO sample paper question regarding functions

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

I am not sure whether this is a PRMO previous year question, but this too came in today's PRMO paper that I had.The question is like this :

> Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function ($ x \neq 0$) such that $3f(x) - 2f(\frac{1}{x}) = x$. Then, find $12f(4)$ .

My main doubt is whether my solution is correct(only regarding the function part and not the actual solution), and if there are simpler solutions.

My approach :

$\because 3f(x) - 2f(\frac{1}{x}) = x$,

$$ f(x) = \frac{x + 2f(\frac{1}{x})}{3}$$
Using this substitution, taking $3f(x)$ as a constant term,

$3f(x) - 2f(\frac{1}{x}) = 3f(x) - 2(\frac{\frac{1}{x} + 2f(x)}{3})$

$ = 3f(x) - \frac{2}{3x} -\frac{4}{3}f(x) = x$
$ = \frac{5}{3}f(x) = x + \frac{2}{3x}$
$\implies$

$$ f(x) = \frac{3x}{5}+\frac{2}{5x}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your solution is correct.

Alternatively you have $$3f(x)-2f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x \space (1)$$
$$3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-2f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\space (2)$$

So $3\cdot(1)+2\cdot(2)$ gives $$5f(x)=3x+\frac{2}{x}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{3x}{5}+\frac{2}{5x}.$$

Comment: Thanks, @ Äres !I am a guy with no idea of dealing with functions. It's the first time I answered such a question correctly !

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x = 4$ and $x = \dfrac{1}{4}$ in the given functional equation to obtain a system of equations:

\begin{align} 3 f \left( 4 \right) - 2 f \left( \dfrac{1}{4} \right) &= 4 \\ -2 f \left( 4 \right) + 3 f \left( \dfrac{1}{4} \right) &= \dfrac{1}{4} \end{align}

Upon solving this equation, you arrive at $f \left( 4 \right) = \dfrac{5}{2}$. Hence, $12 f \left( 4 \right) = 30$.

Comment: Is this the simplest way ?

Comment: @Spectre, because you only needed the value of $12f(4)$, this way is the simplest one. However, the method you have used is more general and actually gives $f$ in terms of $x$ so that any value can be found.

Comment: Thanks, @AniruddhaDeshmukh !

Answer (score 1):

You are right $12f(4)=12/6+1/10=5/3$

Yo may do it flight;y differently by Assuming $f(x)-A, f(1/x)=B$
So the given equation is $$2A-2B=x~~~~(1)$$
If you change $x \to 1/x$ in the original equation, you get
$$2B-2A=1/x~~~~(2)$$
Solfing them you get $$A=f(x)=3x/5+2/(5x), B= f(1/x) =2x/5+3/(5x),$$
which ate mutially consistent.

Comment: Consistent, I guess ... @ZAhmed

Comment: @spectre  Oh, yes.