# Given some arbitrary function $y = f(x)$, if you only know $y$ when given the associated $x$, what is the fastest way of finding $x$ s.t. $f(x) = 0$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, computational-mathematics

For full disclosure, this was a problem I saw on glassdoor that was supposedly asked in an interview. I hope it's OK to ask here; I am not being asked to solve this, I just thought it was a very interesting problem.

I am not sure if the problem was exactly posed as stated in the title, so I make some clarifications: (i) Assume the function definitely takes $0$ for some value in the domain. (ii) When we say "we only know $y$ when given $x$", I think we can treat the function as if it is some sort of oracle, telling you its value at that point in the domain. But we don't have an explicit function.

I can't even see how this is necessarily solvable as stated. I just don't see how finite (or even countable) sampling of a continuous function will guarantee our ability to find the zero. Especially since the function is arbitrary, we could end up with pathological functions that mean some clever approach would fail. The usual computational methods I am aware of such as Newton's method, bijection, Secant etc. all don't work.

I am quite baffled, can anyone please give me some hint or mathematical way of approaching this?

Comment: you can't find a unique function under such conditions without a second point or without the graph. There could be hundreds of functions that might yield the same $y$ at the same $x$ as in your question.

Comment: The problem is missing a lot of context. There is no way to mathematically answer this question without that context.

Comment: @Spectre Yes I think without more specific constraints, there's an infinite number of functions that simply make this unsolvable

Comment: @Somos I agree. I think it's quite clear now that there was probably some specification of continuity. I think with that some solutions become fairly straightforward, though I am not sure what would be most efficient necessarily.

Comment: Unfortunately, even continuity or analyticity would not be enough here. There are severe problems with the question. There could **be** no unique answer.

Comment: @masiewpao  I have put up an answer.

Comment: @Somos Ah... I immediately assumed 'bijection iteration', but that would at best be approximate. Hmm, perhaps the question was miquoted, or they wanted to see how you think about it I suppose.

Comment: Can we assume that you're allowed to call $f(x)$ as many (finite) times as you want, with any $x$ ?

Comment: My *guess* is that whoever asked the question is assuming that $f$ is analytic, or at least reasonably well-behaved. Not something like the Boolean function $\rm is\_trancendental$. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes that was my thought too! Although it is interesting, as Somos mentioned, continuity doesn't necessarily help. I haven't given too much to it being analytic which I will do now however! Perhaps it's possible to find some (non-unique) value

Comment: On second thoughts, even being analytic doesn't help. Given a finite set of $(x,y)$ pairs, you can always interpolate arbitrary points in between the existing points, using (for example) [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 0):

You can't find a unique function under such conditions without a second point or without the graph. There could be hundreds of functions that might yield the same $y$ at the same $x$ as in your question.

However, if some conditions are added as hints [as in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842113/prmo-sample-paper-question-regarding-functions), you can do at least something algebraic to get hold of a possible function.

Comment: Can I ask why you reference hundreds of functions?

Comment: @masiewpao , needn't be hundreds - they could be _uncountably many_ in number.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, specifying hundreds seem to imply there is a finite number of possibilities

Comment: A second point (or even hundreds of points) doesn't help, if the function is sufficiently pathological. Sure, you might find an interval containing a sign change, but that's no guarantee that the interval contains a zero if it's not continuous in that interval.